# Strange corruption of video from mobile phone on my PC

Tags: video, android

I have two videos on my mobile phone, and I want to transfer them to my PC. Let's call them Video A and Video B.

On my phone I see Video A and Video B correctly (they're obviously different videos), but, when I connect my phone to my PC, I see Video A correctly, but, when I click on Video B, I see Video A. All the metadata that I can get from the file of Video B is actually the one from Video A. And, when I delete Video A, Video B becomes unaccesible.
This same thing happens on two different computers, so I suspect about the mobile's internal memory.
My question is: Is there anything wrong with my mobile, if so, can I fix it?

PD: My mobile is a Samsung Galaxy Trend Plus, and both of these videos are on the internal memory of the phone.

**EDIT 1:**
So far, this only happens with these two videos

**EDIT 2:**
I've rebooted the phone and nothing has happened. Also, I noticed that by using Samsung Kies, when I play the video from the Kies app, it works, but, when I download it to my PC, the same error happens.

Comment: Does this happen with only these two videos or with other videos too? If it's recurring this might be one of the weirdest android stories I've heard so far... Maybe  `adb shell dumpsys` and/or `adb logcat` can be of service to you, if you're able to use [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb)

Comment: So far, this only happens with these two videos

Comment: I assume during saving of the second video the filesystem messed up somehow. Maybe a wrong reference. What you could try is force to rebuild android's media database. [Ghost Commander](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.ghostsq.commander/) has this ability. If that and a full reboot does nothing there's little we can do without having more insight. `logcat` might display relevant information or at least some kind of error when you try to access the file on the phone.

Comment: After rebboting my phone by, turning it off, removing the battery, waiting 10 secs, reinsrting the battery and , finally booting it again, nothing has changed. There doens't appear to be any error when I play Video B, not on the phone, not on the computer. The only thing is that on the computer is plays the video that it isn't supposed to play. Also, by using Samsung Kies, when I play the video from the Kies app, it works, but, when I download it to my PC, the same error happens. @confetti If you thing the logs would be helpful, please tell me how can I get them and what to search for on them.

Comment: Well the simplest solution would be you get https://f-droid.org/en/packages/protect.videoeditor/ this app and re-encode the video on the phone, then transfer the new video to the PC and delete the old one.

Comment: @confetti I'm afraid I can't install that app you suggested because the latest android version that I can install on my phone is 4.2.2 Do you know about any other app that would do the same thing and work on my phone? Preferably, I'd like to use an app that doesn't require the device to be rooted. (My phone isn't rooted)

Comment: You should check the app store for "video encoding" apps and see what there is. None of these apps should require root.

Comment: @confetti I tried using the [FFmpeg app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.silentlexx.ffmpeggui&hl=es) for android, but, when I tried to re-encode the video, it gave an error. On the error image the only information was the imput file, the output file, the preset used for encoding, and a timer that reads: 0:00:00.

Comment: Seems like the second video is more corrupted than I thought at first. I'm out of guesses here, sorry. Depending on how important the video is some last resort might be to record the screen while the video is playing on the phone.

Comment: @confetti Ok, I'll try that, but, does this mean that my phone's storage is damaged? Can I still trust on it?

Comment: If this is the only file acting strange I would say there was an issue during saving/encoding of the video that messed the file up.